# Limit blogs creation

Tags: multisite, limit

someone knows how to limit the number of blogs creation in a wordpress multisite? (3.6.1).

In the wordpress plugins repository there is [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/limit-blogs-per-user/), but It doesn't work, I think it's not up to date.

Any suggestion would be appreciated, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The signup page has validation hooks. How about something like this?

```
add_filter('wpmu_validate_blog_signup','set_blog_creation_limit');

function set_blog_creation_limit($result) {

    $blogs = get_blogs_of_user($result['user']->ID);

    if (count($blogs) > 2 )
        $result['errors']->add('blogname', __('You have already registered the maximum amount of blogs!'));

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'd do.

Use this add action:

```
add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'myFunction' ); 

// parameters $blog_id, $user_id, $domain, $path, $site_id, $meta
```

And every time a user creates a Blog to check the current blog count **get_blog_count()** and if it's less to reverse the action.

This way you can do an overall limit or limit by user.

Comment: It should be `add_action()`, not `do_action()`.  Also, please provide some detail as to what should be in the `myFunction()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved in this manner.
I can't say if it's the best practice, but this solution fit my needs.

```
function limit_blog_creation_per_user($active_signup)
{
  $blog_limit = 1;
  if( !is_super_admin() )
  {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $current_user->ID );
    if (count($user_blogs) >= $blog_limit ) $active_signup = 'none';
  }
  return $active_signup;
}
add_action('wpmu_active_signup','limit_blog_creation_per_user');
```

Note: this action doesn't change the active_signup value stored in the database!